# Int / Int64 .Net Memory Allocations

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, garbage-collection, heap-memory

I have a large application which averages about 30 mb/sec in memory allocations (per performance monitor bytes allocated/sec measurement). I am trying to cut this down substantially, and the source of the allocations is not obvious.

To instrument things I have recorded my ETW traces for the CLR / GC, and have exported the AllocationTick event, which records every time an additional 100 kilobytes is allocated, and what the object type was that was most recently allocated. This produces a nice size sample set. Three object types account for 70% of my allocations, but they are a bit of a mystery.

1. System.Int64 **30%**
2. System.Int32 **28%**
3. System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite'1[System.Func'3[System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite,System.Object,System.Object]] **12%**

The dataset was ~70 minutes and a million events, so I am quite confident in the numbers.

I am guessing this is somehow indicating that I am creating a lot of pointers on the heap in some unexpected way? (this is an x64 application)

I use some linq and foreach loops, but these should only be creating increment variables on the stack, not the heap.

I am running everything on top of the TPL / Dataflow library as well, which could be generating these.

I am looking for any advice on what may be causing so many heap allocations of int32/64, and perhaps some techniques to isolate these allocations (call stacks would be great, but may be performance prohibitive).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am guessing this is somehow indicating that I am creating a lot of pointers on the heap in some unexpected way?

It sounds more likely that you're boxing a lot of `int` and `long` values to me.

The `CallSite` part sounds like you're using `dynamic` a lot (or in one very heavily-used part of the code), which can easily lead to more boxing than statically typed code.

I would try to isolate particular areas of the code which allocate a lot of your objects - if you can exercise just specific code paths, for example, that would give you a much clearer idea of which of those paths generates more garbage than you'd expect. Have a look at anywhere that uses `dynamic` and see whether you actually need to - although you shouldn't feel you have to remove *all* uses of `dynamic` by any means; there may well be one particuar "hot spot" that could be micro-optimized.

The other thing to consider is how much this allocation is actually costing you. You say you're trying to cut down on it substantially - do you really need to? If all of these objects are very short-lived, you may well find that you don't improve performance much by reducing the allocation rate. You should measure time spent in garbage collection to work out how effective this is likely to be.

Comment: The dynamic insight was a huge hint. I only use dynamic in a few places for debugging purposes, and in the same debugging code I am boxing the result. Thanks!

Comment: On a separate note - unbelievably helpful, and quick response. I don't know when you sleep to be as responsive as you are (It's midnight here in CA). The allocations are short lived, but they are triggering pauses multiple times per second due to the Gen-0 collection which is causing some fat tail events in our application.

Comment: @Superman: I sleep about midnight to 6am Europe/London time during the week, and midnight to 7am on the weekends :) Sounds like you're in a pretty ideal situation to optimize though, with just a few hotspots - always a nice position to be in.